# VSCode jshint disable E058 and W030 for async functions

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, jshint

I am trying to disable the `W030` and the `E058` errors thrown by `jshint` for vscode, but am getting `Bad option '-E058` when I set it in the beginning of the file using `/* jshint -E058 */`. This method with `-W030` works fine.

Both of these errors are thrown while using `async` and `await`. I know that I can use `eshint` to overcome this, but really trying to do this via `jshint` instead.

If i could also see a sample on how to do this via `package.json` using `jshintConfig`, it would be very helpful. Based on searches, I couldnt find a direct mapping to the `jshint` short code to the code mappings. Being able to ignore these errors globally will be even more helpful.